# If I hot swap a power supply to a larger wattage, will it damage the server?

Tags: dell-poweredge, power-supply-unit, hotswap

I have a Dell Poweredge R720 server with 2x redundant 750 Watt power supplies. If I wanted to upgrade those to 1100 Watts without shutting down the server and go through the process of hot swapping them, at some point there will be one 750W and one 1100W power supply running. Would this configuration cause any damage while I'm in the process of upgrading?

I have 2x 115W cpus, 128Gb DDR3 EEC RAM and 16x 2.5" 10k spinning drives. It should remain below 750W draw while the upgrade is happening.

I'd just like some confirmation on this. Any reference documentation could be useful too.

Comment: Why do the PSU's require upgraded power capacity?

Comment: @ewwhite I'm upgrading the PSUs because I want to install an Nvidia Tesla card which can take up to an additional 300 Watts of power. Currently, there is no functional issues with my current setup.

Comment: You should add that to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

No concern for damage and expected error logs, but disabling PSU is likely.

"Supporting all PSU combinations adds unnecessary cost and complexity to the design."

More details: https://downloads.dell.com/solutions/general-solution-resources/White%20Papers/PSU%20Mismatch%20System%20Behavior%20for%20Dell%20PowerEdge%20Servers.pdf

Comment: It looks like I'd be doing a Output Capacity Mismatch scenario. You've probably read the document but cliff notes for those who haven't: Two PSU's with mismatched wattage, the higher wattage is the **primary** PSU and the lower wattage one will be disabled and removeable. The example they give says that the newly hot plugged PSU will be disabled (even if its wattage is greater). **Summary** is that I'd be better off shutting down the server and replacing both rather than inserting one, having it disabled, and then turning my server off by removing the other (potentially).

Answer (score 1):

The Dell sever may complain about the mismatch power supplies but other than that you have the right idea about staying under the 750W limit. Ohms Law dictates power draw. If the resistance suddenly dropped because of a short in the system, the mismatched PSUs still wouldn't be the issue to focus on.